# Why can't I move-construct a unique_ptr with itself?

Tags: c++, c++11, unique-ptr, clang++, std-function

I was recently working with some code that uses a `std::vector` of `std::unique_ptr<T>` with a custom deleter of type `std::function<void(T*)>`. The code is attempting to remove values that meet a certain condition from the vector:

```
size_t j = 0;
for (size_t i = 0; i < vec.size(); i++) {
    if (!condition(vec[i].get()) {
            vec[j] = std::move(out[i]);
            j++;
    }
}
vec.resize(j);
```

In troubleshooting a `bad_function_call` thrown from the destructor of `vec`, I found that when `i=j` and a `unique_ptr` is move-constructed with itself, it loses its custom deleter. In other words, `vec[j]` will still point to the correct value, but its deleter will be a default-constructed `std::function`.

Why does this happen? What rule does this code break?

FWIW, I can only make it happen with clang, and only on certain platforms. Adding a guard for `i=j` fixes the problem.

**MCVE**:

```
#include <memory>
#include <vector>
#include <functional>

using int_ptr= std::unique_ptr<int, std::function<void(int*)>>;

int_ptr make_int_ptr(int val) {
    auto deleter = [](int* q) { delete q; };
    int* v = new int;
    *v = val;
    return int_ptr{v, deleter};
}

int main() {
    auto a = make_int_ptr(4);
    a = std::move(a);
}
```

Comment: please create a [MCVE]

Comment: actually `unique_ptr` self assign is well defined (and work as intended), the `std::function` seems not though.

Comment: and there is no way to move *construct* self afaict.

Answer (score 4):

Standard library classes are not required to check for self-assignment from an rvalue. According to [res.on.arguments]/(1.3),

> If a function argument binds to an rvalue reference parameter, the implementation may assume that
>   this parameter is a unique reference to this argument.

Thus, undefined behaviour occurs when you try to perform a self-move-assignment.